The import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate cannot be resolved
When I try to import the 'SimpleJdbcTemplate' class it gives me the following error.
The 'SimpleJdbcTemplate' cannot be resolved in my Spring project.
(import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate;)
I have added the following maven dependencies in my pom.xml file.
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


That class doesn't exists anymore. Use either JdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

You could have looked up for yourself that this class no longer exists in v6+: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/package-summary.html

@M.Deinum    I have used JdbcTemplate.  It worked fine. Thanks.
